# On screen buttons not working in google cardboard

Tags: canvas, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

Hi there I am creating an app with google cardboard sdk, I will not be using it in the google cardboard as I would like to have on screen buttons, however If i place the buttons any where on the screen but the center the buttons wont work(you cant click on them). NB: I am using the prefab with the gaze pointer, I assumed it has something to do with the raycast from the gazepointer but I have tried deactivating the gazepointer and it still wont work. Please help me :) My project is due on monday :'(

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure TapIsTrigger is false on the Cardboard object.  Second, on the EventSystem you need to manage the InputModules.  When GazeInputModule is active, and higher than TouchInputModule in the component list, then it gets all touch events and treats them as triggers applied to objects in the scene (including WorldSpace canvases).  If you want to use touch to operate ScreenSpace canvases, you need to deactivate GazeInputModule or make sure it is below TouchInputModule in the list, so that TouchInputModule receives the screen touch events.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no idea the event system was different to the normal one. You directed me to the root of the problem, I also had to activate Force Module on the touch input module. The only thing now is, that I cant use the gaze pointer and buttons at the same time, though I can work around this by using a canvas in world space that follows the player or having swipe input to activate the module and deactivate gazepoint. Thank you so much, you are a life saver :)